# How to solve package incompatibility when adding wagmi viem to React/Typescript project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, react-scripts, wagmi

I am trying to add wagmi and viem packages to the project. My project has react-scripts package and I am using the latest version 5.0.1. Typescript is running with version 4.9.5. However, when I try to add wagmi and viem, the typescript is requested in minimum version 5.0.4. How can I solve this problem?

```
npm i wagmi viem

 - npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
 - npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
 - npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
 - npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
 - npm ERR!
 - npm ERR! While resolving: viem@1.2.12
 - npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.9.5
 - npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
 - npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@">=5.0.4" from @wagmi/chains@1.2.0
 - npm ERR!   node_modules/viem/node_modules/@wagmi/chains
 - npm ERR!     @wagmi/chains@"1.2.0" from viem@1.2.12
 - npm ERR!     node_modules/viem
 - npm ERR!       viem@"*" from the root project
 - npm ERR!
 - npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
 - npm ERR! peerOptional typescript@">=5.0.4" from viem@1.2.12
 - npm ERR! node_modules/viem
 - npm ERR!   viem@"*" from the root project
 - npm ERR!
 - npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: typescript@5.1.6
 - npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
 - npm ERR!   peerOptional typescript@">=5.0.4" from viem@1.2.12
 - npm ERR!   node_modules/viem
 - npm ERR!     viem@"*" from the root project
 - npm ERR!
 - npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
 - npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
 - npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Answer (score 0):

`viem@1.2.12` and `@wagmi/chains@1.2.0` packages require TypeScript as their [peer dependency](https://nodejs.org/fa/blog/npm/peer-dependencies) and the version should be `>=5.0.4`. The warning will display when you are using npm v7+(Node v15+).

```
$ npm view viem@1.2.12 peerDependencies
{ typescript: '>=5.0.4' }

$ npm view @wagmi/chains@1.2.0 peerDependencies
{ typescript: '>=5.0.4' }
```

1. Upgrading TypeScript to version `>=5.0.4`:

```
npm i typescript@^5.0.4 -D
```

2. See [Allow TypeScript 5+ in peerDependencies](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/13071#issuecomment-1517278541) and [Announcing TypeScript 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/)

> 5.0 is not a disruptive release, and everything you know is still applicable.

So you can use the `--legacy-peer-deps` option

`npm i wagmi viem --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: I have to use react-scripts. The requirement of react-script is that the typescript should be maximum version 4.9.5. Your recommendation for this situation does not work.

Comment: @SEB Updated answer, try it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar issue. It is not with wagmi viem but I found a workaround on this GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/13080#issuecomment-1487975896). I hope it helped.